# Two combined Generics result on Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)

Tags: typescript, recursion, optimization, expand

I'm kind of new to Typescript and I would need some help to fix the error `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)`

The playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/PTAEEkDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrAzqAssgDqAPIBGAVrKtBgFDXQCeesoAwspAEKwCiAHnuwAmsQQB4AKqFi84kQVgD2ZCtFABeUEvKUANKAAi60BmjwAlpADmAPiMBvaqFAA3ZABsArrABcocY9BhFA83aF99agBfWgs4JDRmDmQMZgcomJgEFHRQAFUU%20CkZWDksJJTQByczQV8TcysdAPgFNx9Wdi4%20ATkRUQAlVthrJqdIBTg60wtLJujqWKyE0EG2otl5UHLUgJqphtmAjwLfNk4efiE%20-IQRgN59mfTqED8ACzMsRficgHczNxuUDEZjSHrCQSgCygVBmeCoELIQq-ZD0AB0oAWmR%20zAAGusSpttpVdrVjNNGgFIMgALbteozUagY4IU6dC7g64FO5OFptNnnbpXMSrYbNIYYAVdS69EVDADaAF1rM8XmAABKwNxMQqIDyQShmBSQNG0BhMUAAKQUFlEAGk9AAFWwaO0E0rkg6gAA%20oEgHhpIMKAH4Ak5He7NgyrD6-QGg6BQ05k8mAAYAEjsdsimYARLnI1gI8HQPnQL5c2jczm7I7Iqmwyny37YM4EM3IK2EABuM2MZiO%20CwRBmXgAdTM0DeokdegAynoWEYAORo5cu0AR6QbLDL5eJ0AZuzRyygABkoDn9ebR5P583NbvF5Yj4pp4vV4bdH7l7wbknE5TgAgoCjoKBgGBmMQbQsAogYWMg0BGpAGCiHOhaeoyBgYSeLqNne26Elg6Elne3iNim6GER6e4HrR5FNoxl4YUeFiIO24g1voNZse2uTXkmTFCZIvrWra4jzn%20AGTm8IFuGBEFQTBcHEAhSHGqhuR6Po1gqkJQm%20HOva0GqODINCeoGupkCYi8ABUdmOHZ7yfKAlmGsaoD-ICoBDtAHjwDZ7hAng4GQapawANawPQWBTohMLsMCoIyhCmg2UBjrgHoxpuPQoDQAoBVvMwABygSwLABBtG2bhOcA34WnaMUYGc0qcmIEmgOV1GbP6gYINpVVThh-VBkqG49cUHr6MNbzysubRWFOy6KgenZtoUvgBJIvVYG1HLCgejbNbFB1CrKEgLa4niwKteilUNeBTrY20prt02bEB8DwKioi8YUuS2CWp2teyF0QqIWndU9L3NhRmKMR9O6aMolDHUxVRCfKbrQtF9AKIgfigGtb3CTja17aj2iqCWiP6SmbpU3evpjQgCMM5zTYlke2aprGYmQKIvP1nooPnalfTiBTD16PKACMehosrs3PW8yp6VzWuMb4G3s9rBvJrrXbwBzhtMRzkTyvjhN%20GtHNkymeum7QwAOU5oAQ6A%20OKDZqaEPzxDJCIwL5amoP8wIv10nEpqgHZDXmswEMAPqiIQYstU6OFvg9o3xu2sNvBh%20qReMvyQEqoB4SmU0o6rU4LUtlgrWtJYI4QGESx1GNMYQC1BMgITQKt8NCZ3jtEF34OS5CgmMan6fylun1YKDdE3V4%206%20Mug-D-doCg06ssGHNr1m53VPfb99D-ZA7GA8DZspov0NH5uJ8N281hKs-RtT1TLQKhEx-ycFjbWOMoQ2RtkTQgioAC0wZfCL37naRUmdYpOiHCOccMkZxixGDDUACslYqzmsqUBoBohc18J3Eyrw5xwWYHAEwkpEb2UcvHT2lxITfGyHiAqRUpzMAACygBqlqDEY4FDwEihgAAhB7D2bRVAPFLCyeABZfS5j5LALRpZdEYH0bmDRaJdHGN0WiDRFihhWIKGYoY%20iPYmPsZY6xsYXEIAcW0OxXjzEeLca42x7jtGGN8Zo2MziwmmP8aEiU4TvGwHCbmeq1AVGgDUeLGeHVRC4j0CIuWFDXbuy4R7L2JAaah1AEiVSpgkT5R9ulQ8dpUwYlwLwCqVUKpMBgJsTypUMSgGkbIhRSiuHiA%20Fgdy1koRYH%20FOBQHhVDCOaRhLJgpZ4SGsK0xGzkSDOE%20HlCAgRjSqDeMgNs1TID5SHoVVAcE-ywDgN7FqTS7Rx2cqkpO3DwQSAwtsMWOcvQaGdnnKmbNCgaBERuReXU5xSWgIBWSoEwpKVgLBeC1JrKoSZqvTCMYQbNj3HoVc64SXLhPhNWg6T6Dy2QalXJKo3acOcjSgATL4cBUIyQnl7E7Wk9I3x8uTBox4VhhW8iGGKywErfISmlb2ahCdqVPNAPQDlPyhC5JJTE4JQSfEaPXBwj22AZHMHuTSR5HSwTsEgsaKRMjIqgBAhgIqZgibgGZBUZAoAaRms6QQfG1SsBiLGay1V6rOWNj2PimVjZqR0gVY2UVJIhIxt5WbXRUaubpqFZQlNXKc08rzYbLNsbZVc3GJMctlDIgVqYmojNQk61myrYKg4sqW0pjLU25Mhik1Koasa0pXDwAephCpCwzC3jgWYb8Iq0zkIYD0BM81DyATthMEiVQGAZ2-AYp8rhuZxA-gsFumAZhELIVmUUdAilar5WEF0oQoBQqKWgvlNiFhJxJIABRsoAKwAA4ACcABKFJI7nLqgUL8RKNlPV4CHG2GAxVPhJkPc5XIBo4J0lQ52GQ4ip2COMJVYqoIfoyI%20UOkA3yIZsr%20VTAFh81ktW7sKCQ%20TCkblBd1fOA1IWgGhUYWFkl-yIpknJBS4VlKYqvRpe0QKZgHjdDvCloBSWEOJUQqlQA).

To see the error uncomment the Type `ExpandThrowAnError`.

Background.

I have created two Generics to help me with API definition. Each object returned by API can have some keys that can be expanded if required during the request.

So the generic `KeysCanBeExpanded` helps me to get all keys on the object that can be expanded and `Expand` helps me to expand the object with keys that I pass to it.

Separately, as you will see on the playground, the two Generics works like charm, but if I combine them together the compiler starts to complain and tell `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)`

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing; I've certainly seen the Playground slow down when trying to compile particularly nasty types, so hopefully it's possible for you to do the same here.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much for your comment. I will update the question with the minimal reproducible example as you asked, ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to compute the types that cause problems step by step:

From:

```js
type ExpandWithError<T extends Base, K extends KeysCanBeExpanded<T, N> = never, N extends number = 4> = Expand_<T, SplitWithAllPossibleCombinations<K extends string ? K : '', '.'>, '', N, []>
```

To:

```js
type Expand<T extends Base, K extends KeysCanBeExpanded<T, N> extends infer R ? R : never = never, N extends number = 4> = Expand_<T, SplitWithAllPossibleCombinations<K extends string ? K : '', '.'> extends infer Ko ? Ko: '', '', N, []>
```